# how to connect cucumber to oracle database to validate an xml

Tags: ruby, cucumber

How to connect cucumber to oracle database to validate an xml
this code is in mysql and i need in plsql
require 'mysql2'

```
begin
    # Initialize connection variables.
    host = String('mydemoserver.mysql.database.azure.com')
    database = String('quickstartdb')
    username`enter code here` = String('myadmin@mydemoserver')
    password = String('yourpassword')

    # Initialize connection object.
    client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => host, :username => username, :database => database, :password => password)
    puts 'Successfully created connection to database.'

    # Read data
    resultSet = client.query('SELECT * from inventory;')
    resultSet.each do |row|
        puts 'Data row = (%s, %s, %s)' % [row['id'], row['name'], row['quantity']]
    end
    puts 'Read ' + resultSet.count.to_s + ' row(s).'

# Error handling
rescue Exception => e
    puts e.message

# Cleanup
ensure
    client.close if client
    puts 'Done.'
end
```

Comment: what cucumber is to do with oracle database connection?

Comment: Query an xml in a table